# MySQL - Select only the rows that have not been selected in the last read

Tags: mysql

### Problem description

I have a table, say `trans_flow`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE trans_flow (
    id BIGINT(20) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    card_no VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    money INT(20) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

New data is inserted into this table constantly.

Now, I want to fetch only the rows that have not been fetched in the last query. For example, at 5:00, `id` ranges from 1 to 100, and I read the rows 80 - 100 and do some processing. Then, at 5:01, the id comes to 150, and I want to get exactly the rows 101 - 150. Otherwise, the processing program will read in old and already processed data. Note that such queries are committed continuously. From a certain perspective, I want to implement "streaming process" on MySQL.

### A tentative idea

I have a simple but maybe ugly solution. I create an auxiliary table `query_cursor` which stores the beginning and end ids of one query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE query_cursor (
    task_id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'Specify which task is reading this table',
    first_row_id BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    last_row_id BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

During each query, I first update the query range stored in this table by:

```sql
UPDATE query_cursor
SET first_row_id = (SELECT last_row_id + 1 FROM query_cursor WHERE task_id = 'xxx'),
    last_row_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM trans_flow)
WHERE task_id = 'xxx'
```

And then, doing query on table `trans_flow` using stored cursors:

```sql
SELECT * FROM trans_flow
WHERE id BETWEEN (SELECT first_row_id FROM query_cursor WHERE task_id = 'xxx')
         AND (SELECT last_row_id FROM query_cursor WHERE task_id = 'xxx')
```

### Question for help

Is there a simpler and more elegant implementation that can achieve the same effect (the best if no need to use an auxiliary table)? The version of MySQL is 5.7.

Comment: Is your process single-threaded or multi-threaded? Do you need concurrency control?

Comment: @TheImpaler There are many tasks (or threads) to read data from the same table `trans_flow`, but one task is only single-threaded.

Comment: What is critical - fetching rows or processing fetched rows? If rows were fetched but not processed due to some reason (abort/error/hang/etc.) - does they must be fetched again for to perform the processing?

Comment: @Akina Thank you for pointing out this. Yes, I want to have "rollback"-like effect if the process is failed. But if it is hard to implement, it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: I'd prefer to add a column into source table. During fetch this column should be assigned the unique id of the thread which takes this row (not the whole rowset! one separate row) for processing, and after processing complete it is replaced with "completed" mark.

Comment: @Akina Well, but one row in `trans_flow` can be used for multiple tasks at the same time. So if you use a simple flag-mark, it will mask a mess. Maybe I didn't explain clearly the "single-threaded process". I mean the process to the fetched data is single-threaded, but there are many threads to select the data from the table individually.

Comment: @Akina For example, Thread A selects the users from `trans_flow` with money > 100 and send message to them instantly, while Thread B selects the users with money > 200 and send another message to them instantly. Thread A and Thread B are independent each other. No relationship between this two threads.  And that is the reason for column `task_id` in my created table `query_cursor`.

Comment: I.e. row-its processing is M:N relation? If so then, like for any M:N, not column but adjacency table.